# Average course size per department

Tags: sql

I am trying to write an SQL query that returns for each department, the department name and average number of students enrolled in courses offered by that departmen.
There are three tables here,

Students

```
NetId   VARCHAR(10)
FirstName   VARCHAR(255)
LastName    VARCHAR(255)
Department  VARCHAR(100)
```

Enrollments

```
NetId   VARCHAR(10)
CRN INT
Credits INT
Score   REAL
```

Courses

```
CRN INT
Title   VARCHAR(255)
Department  VARCHAR(100)
Instructor  VARCHAR(255)
```

I have written

```
select c.Department,
       (select e.CRN as col1, count(e.NetId) as col2
        from Enrollments e
          join Courses c on e.CRN = c.CRN
        group by e.CRN) as t
```

but don't know how to go on.

Here is the expected result:
Accounting 4
CS 4
ECE 4
Music 4
Physics 4
Psychology 4
Sports 4
Economics 3
Finance 3
Statistics 3

Comment: Welcome to SO. For how to go on, first figure out which RDBMS you're using, then please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `real` is a poor data choice for storing someone's "score" (which is likely a integer value). Floating point values are inaccurate, and you will easily introduce inaccuracies with such a data type.

Comment: What database app are you using? Edit tags.

Comment: Should probably have a Departments table and only save DeptID instead of Department names. Why is department in Students - is this their major?

Comment: This is a class assignment? So essentially, total students enrolled in classes in each department divided by total courses with students in each department for the average course enrollment in each department? Don't consider courses that do not have students nor students not enrolled in courses? Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: Not showing raw data. Not providing RDBMS used.

Answer (score 0):

This is an aggregation query.  I would use `LEFT JOIN` to include students with no courses:

```
select c.Department,
       count(e.CRN) as num_students,
       count(distinct c.CRN) as num_departments,
       count(e.CRN) / count(distinct c.CRN) as avg_students_in_class
from Courses c left join
     Enrollments e
     on e.CRN = c.CRN
group by c.department
```

Comment: thx! but still have some problem, the answer use ceiling, I also add a ceiling here but there still have mistakes. The expected answer is CS 4
Psychology 4
+  Statistics 4
Accounting 3
ECE 3
Economics 3
Finance 3
Music 3
Physics 3
Sports 3